# Rails Validates less than 0 or greater than 0, or field not equal to 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've added validation to my Rails model for `less_than` and `greater_than`, but they obviously conflict each other.

I want to make sure Rails validates a field on model to never be 0.  So less than OR greater than 0, but not both because that's not possible.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is already a validator for this called `numericality`

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  validates :salary, numericality: { other_than: 0 }
end
```

Answer (score 6):

```
validate :non_zero

def non_zero
  if self.field_name == 0
     self.errors.add(:field_name, "Field can't be zero")
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd name that `non_zero`.

Comment: @MartinSvalin agreed. changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :field, exclusion: { in: [0] }
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion

works for fields that allow nil values; easy to test